# Job fails on Mesos cluster

Tags: mesos, marathon

I am running — currently on a single machine — one Mesos master, one slave, one Zookeeper and Marathon. All are running inside a Docker container.
They all seem to be communicating with each other correctly.

***NOTE:*** Usually Mesos master runs on port 5050 and slaves on port 5051. The port 5050 was already used by some other app on my machine, so **master** runs on port **5051** and **slave** on port **5052**.

Through Marathon, I then try to run the basic-0 example, but the job keeps failing. I used to be able to run jobs, but I made some changes to the way I was running the Docker containers, in order to remove all local ips.

---

I run Mesos containers with the following parameters :

**Master :**

```
docker run --net=host -d \
       -e MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY="/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so" \
       -e MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY="/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so" \
       -e MESOS_QUORUM=1 -e MESOS_LOG_DIR='/var/tmp' \
       -e MESOS_WORK_DIR='/tmp' \
       -e MESOS_ZK=zk://$IP:2181/mesos \
       -e MESOS_PORT=5051 \
       -e MESOS_ADVERTISE_PORT=5051 \
       -e MESOS_ADVERTISE_IP=$IP \
       -e MESOS_HOSTNAME=$IP \
       -p 5051:5051 \
       eurobd/mesos-master
```

**Slave :**

```
docker run --net=host -d \
       -e MESOS_MASTER=zk://$IP:2181/mesos \
       -e MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/tmp \
       -e MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT=2mins \
       -e MESOS_ISOLATOR=cgroups/cpu,cgroups/mem \
       -e MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos \
       -e MESOS_HOSTNAME=$IP \
       -e MESOS_ADVERTISE_IP=$IP \
       -e MESOS_IP=$IP \
       -e MESOS_ADVERTISE_PORT=5052 \
       -e MESOS_PORT=5052 \
       -v /run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock \
       -v /sys:/sys \
       -v /proc:/host/proc:ro \
       -p 5052:5052 \
       eurobd/mesos-slave
```

---

Here are the various logs that I read, but didn't help me :

Executor stderr :

```
I0517 10:00:48.011389   125 logging.cpp:188] INFO level logging started!
I0517 10:00:48.012583   125 exec.cpp:143] Version: 0.28.0
I0517 10:00:48.013772   130 exec.cpp:472] Slave exited ... shutting down
```

Executor stdout... `Shutting down` (nothing more)

[Slave logs (only a part):](http://pastie.org/10840729)

```
I0517 10:00:47.705261    11 slave.cpp:4374] Current disk usage 0.63%. Max allowed age: 6.256098991214965days
I0517 10:00:47.888465     7 slave.cpp:1361] Got assigned task basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003 for framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:47.889526     7 gc.cpp:83] Unscheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000' from gc
I0517 10:00:47.889643    10 gc.cpp:83] Unscheduling '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000' from gc
I0517 10:00:47.889832     7 slave.cpp:1480] Launching task basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003 for framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:47.890251     7 paths.cpp:528] Trying to chown '/tmp/mesos/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000/executors/basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003/runs/01392987-0e53-4175-a019-d7b2ba815287' to user 'root'
I0517 10:00:47.894273     7 slave.cpp:5367] Launching executor basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003 of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000 with resources cpus(*):0.1; mem(*):32 in work directory '/tmp/mesos/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000/executors/basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003/runs/01392987-0e53-4175-a019-d7b2ba815287'
I0517 10:00:47.894803    11 docker.cpp:1009] No container info found, skipping launch
I0517 10:00:47.894989     7 slave.cpp:1698] Queuing task 'basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003' for executor 'basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003' of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:47.895226     6 containerizer.cpp:666] Starting container '01392987-0e53-4175-a019-d7b2ba815287' for executor 'basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003' of framework 'c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000'
I0517 10:00:47.898272    13 launcher.cpp:147] Forked child with pid '124' for container '01392987-0e53-4175-a019-d7b2ba815287'
I0517 10:00:47.898432    13 containerizer.cpp:1118] Checkpointing executor's forked pid 124 to '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000/executors/basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003/runs/01392987-0e53-4175-a019-d7b2ba815287/pids/forked.pid'
I0517 10:00:49.904361     6 slave.cpp:1891] Asked to kill task basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003 of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:49.904460     6 slave.cpp:3002] Handling status update TASK_KILLED (UUID: 10164116-b7eb-480f-841e-830f9301e174) for task basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003 of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000 from @0.0.0.0:0
I0517 10:00:49.905267     7 status_update_manager.cpp:320] Received status update TASK_KILLED (UUID: 10164116-b7eb-480f-841e-830f9301e174) for task basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003 of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:49.905645     7 status_update_manager.cpp:824] Checkpointing UPDATE for status update TASK_KILLED (UUID: 10164116-b7eb-480f-841e-830f9301e174) for task basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003 of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:49.984380    11 slave.cpp:3400] Forwarding the update TASK_KILLED (UUID: 10164116-b7eb-480f-841e-830f9301e174) for task basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003 of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000 to master@MASTER_IP:5051
I0517 10:00:50.013109     7 status_update_manager.cpp:392] Received status update acknowledgement (UUID: 10164116-b7eb-480f-841e-830f9301e174) for task basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003 of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:50.013226     7 status_update_manager.cpp:824] Checkpointing ACK for status update TASK_KILLED (UUID: 10164116-b7eb-480f-841e-830f9301e174) for task basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003 of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:53.040210     7 containerizer.cpp:1608] Executor for container '01392987-0e53-4175-a019-d7b2ba815287' has exited
I0517 10:00:53.040279     7 containerizer.cpp:1392] Destroying container '01392987-0e53-4175-a019-d7b2ba815287'
I0517 10:00:53.042726    11 provisioner.cpp:306] Ignoring destroy request for unknown container 01392987-0e53-4175-a019-d7b2ba815287
I0517 10:00:53.042866     8 slave.cpp:3886] Executor 'basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003' of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000 terminated with signal Killed
I0517 10:00:53.042927     8 slave.cpp:3990] Cleaning up executor 'basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003' of framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:53.043233     9 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000/executors/basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003/runs/01392987-0e53-4175-a019-d7b2ba815287' for gc 6.99999950039407days in the future
I0517 10:00:53.043305     9 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000/executors/basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003' for gc 6.99999949956148days in the future
I0517 10:00:53.043344     9 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000/executors/basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003/runs/01392987-0e53-4175-a019-d7b2ba815287' for gc 6.99999949898074days in the future
I0517 10:00:53.043372     8 slave.cpp:4078] Cleaning up framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:53.043376     9 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000/executors/basic-0.3a8b8882-1c16-11e6-89e4-0242ac110003' for gc 6.99999949824296days in the future
I0517 10:00:53.043486    12 status_update_manager.cpp:282] Closing status update streams for framework c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000
I0517 10:00:53.043511     9 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000' for gc 6.99999949670222days in the future
I0517 10:00:53.043563     9 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-S0/frameworks/c0df712a-510c-47f1-84a5-0644c6393726-0000' for gc 6.99999949613333days in the future
```

I can probably give more information, if it isn't enough. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Could you paste the Master's logs too ?